# How to view the source code of functions that are not exported in the R package

Tags: r, function

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/) and would like to use and view the source code of a function that is not exported. But it failed.

The name of this unexported function is `diag()`, which exists in the `coxme` package.

When I type `coxme::diag()` in Console, I can find that the function `diag()` does exist.

```
> coxme::diag()
Error: 'diag' is not an exported object from 'namespace:coxme'
```

But when I type `coxme:::diag()`, I can't find this function. I don't know why. In [this tutorial](https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/), the author successfully to find the function by typing `usethis:::base_and_recommended()`.

```
> coxme:::diag
Error: object 'diag' not found
```

Comment: Are you sure `diag` makes sense for a mixed effects result?

Comment: `coxme::diag()` error doesn't tell you that the function exists in `coxme` : you'll get the same error with `coxme::functionthatdoesntexist`. If you search `diag`in [coxme source](https://github.com/cran/coxme/search?p=6&q=%22diag%22), you'll see it's `base::diag`

Comment: @ Waldi, Thanks a lot. I posted a new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752786/how-to-find-the-source-code-of-r-package-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(coxme)
getAnywhere(diag)
getAnywhere(diag)[1]
showMethods(diag)
```

```
differing objects matching ‘diag’ were found
in the following places
  package:bdsmatrix
  package:base
  namespace:base
  namespace:Matrix
  namespace:bdsmatrix
Use [] to view one of them

standardGeneric for "diag" defined from package "base"

function (x = 1, nrow, ncol, names = TRUE) 
standardGeneric("diag")
<environment: 0x0000014df6d2a480>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, nrow, ncol, names
Use  showMethods(diag)  for currently available ones.

Function: diag (package base)
x="ANY"
x="bdsmatrix"
x="CsparseMatrix"
x="diagonalMatrix"
x="gchol"
x="gchol.bdsmatrix"
x="indMatrix"
x="packedMatrix"
x="RsparseMatrix"
x="TsparseMatrix"
x="unpackedMatrix"
```